# Why HTTP was designed to be a pull protocol?

Tags: http, html

I was watching many presentations about Html 5 WebSockets , where server can initialize connection with client and push the data without the request from the client.

We don't need Polling etc.

And , I am curious , why Http was designed as a "pull" and not full duplex protocol in the first place ? What where the reasons behind that kind of decision ?

Comment: It seemed a good idea at that time :). Consider that the "Internet" was quite different back then. HTTP now is just a piece of history that we're left with. It is a children's coat, which is not really comfortable when you have matured.

Comment: Now we use HTTP to transfer data that will use other protocols transfer data.

Comment: Note that HTTP/2 adds "push".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because when http was first designed it was meant to be used to retrieve documents from a server. And the easiest way to do is when the client asks the server for a document and gets it delivered as response (or an error in case it does not exist). When you have push protocol that means the server would need to keep client connections around for potentially a long time creating more resource management problems - remember we are talking about early 1990s here.

Comment: +1. It was designed to navigate through documents, not for creating event-based applications. The simplicity of the request/response mechanism is the reason why it is still used today, and the base for [many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) [other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) [protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol).

Answer (score 2):

Http was designed for simply retrieving hypertext documents from a server. There were no reasons to push anything to the client when the pages were just pure, static html without scripting capabilities.

Since there was no need at the time for pushing things back to the client, the protocol was kept simple.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is mainly a pull protocol—someone loads information on a Web server and
users use HTTP to pull the information from the server at their convenience. In particular,
the TCP connection is initiated by the machine that wants to receive the file.