# WordPress shortcode not updating dynamic data

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am building a plugin which has to do with donations and I added a progress bar whose value has to be read from the database.

For example, if I added my shortcode on `/sample-page/` and the value at that moment in the database is `1000`, even if I update the value in the database, the value showing on `/sample-page/` does not change unless the url change for example `/smaple-page/?something=s` then it would load new content and then if the value changes in the database again, I'll need to change the URL for it to render the latest content.

Please help

You can find the code below

```
add_shortcode( $this->donationProgressShortCode,  array($this,'progressBarShortCode'));


 function progressBarShortCode($params){


   if(!isset($params['id']) || !$params['id']){
     return 'ID NOT PROVIDED';
   }

   $model = new Donation();
   $donation = $model->getDonation($params['id']);

   if(!$donation){
     return;
   }

   $target = $donation->target;
   if($target <= 0){
     return;
   }

   $total = 0;
   $percentage = 0;


   $transactions = $model->getTransactions($params['id']);
   if($transactions){
     foreach($transactions as $item){
       // error_log('ITEMS HERE MAN: '.json_encode($item));
       $total+= $item->amount; 
     }
   }

   if($total > 0){
     $percentage = ($total * 100) / $target;
   }


   wp_enqueue_style('tz_payment_gateway_style', $this->pluginUrl . 'assets/style/checkout-style.css');



   $content = '<div style="width: 100%; padding: 2px">
  <div style="display: flex; justify-content-between; font-weight: bold">
    <div style="width: 100%;">'.$total.'<small>'.$donation->currency.'</small></div>
    <div style="width: 100%; text-align: right">'.$target.'<small>'.$donation->currency.'</small></div>
  </div>  
  <div style="position: relative; background-color: #ccc9; border-radius: 5px; overflow: hidden; height: 18px">
    <div style="transition: 11.5s all ease-in; height: 18px; background-color: '.$donation->background_color.'; position: absolute; width:'.($percentage> 100? 100: $percentage).'%; color: transparent">.</div>
    <div style="height: 18px; line-height: 18px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black; color: #fff; width: 100%; position: absolute; text-align: center;">'.$percentage.'%</div>
  </div>
</div>';



   return $content;
 }
```

What I do is basically read all paid transactions from the database then calculate the percentage based on the target amount, then render the result as a progress bar as seen in the image below.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires having JavaScript execute a request from the browser to your server at a regular interval. You will likely need to set up a custom [REST API endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/) to receive requests from the browser via your shortcode. The REST API endpoint would respond with the latest updated value, and your JavaScript would update the web page with this new value.

The server cannot regularly and automatically push data updates to the browser. The browser must regularly send requests to the server. This is why using a different URL worked to update the donations. The browser was making another request to the server.

Comment: @Anseloh My answer helps you to understand what is happening, but it does not give you the code to implement a solution. If you need help with code, please post code for what you have already done along with any questions, and I might be able to make suggestions for a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have updated the question with some code and an image. Using rest api like suggested would work I think. My issue here is Why doesn't it read from the database each time that page is rendered. It would only read and update only if I change a url param like query string

Comment: Hi @Anseloh. Code snippets are ready for you to drop into your WordPress installation for testing. You can access them on [SourceHut](https://paste.sr.ht/~kofeigen/a602c8cd7a8a89c1884a2678b3a28f38cbe72253). They are presented with a README page. There is a lot to learn from these snippets. So, feel free to ask questions (or open another Stack Overflow question). To address your question about why the browser does not update automatically, you can take a look at the answer to this question: [Why HTTP was designed to be a pull protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211723). Thanks.